# Finding the higher-order derivative $\frac{\mathrm{d}^{950}}{\mathrm{d}x^{950}}(\sin x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find $$\frac{\mathrm{d}^{950}}{\mathrm{d}x^{950}}(\sin x)$$

How are really high-order derivatives found? My try:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^{950}}{\mathrm{d}x^{950}}(\sin x)= 950(\cos x)^{949}$$

This doesn't seem right. Help please.

Comment: Can you find the first, second, third, and 4th derivatives?

Comment: Hint: $950=4\cdot 237+2$.

Comment: @Tyler They repeat after the 4th derivative...but how do I determine the answer?

Comment: I changed the title into what you are really asking (literally, the title asks for the $951$-st derivative).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asked to find the 950th derivative of $f(x) = \sin x$.

Observe that $$f'(x) = \cos x, f''(x) = - \sin x, f'''(x) = - \cos x,  f^{(4)}(x) = \sin x = f(x).$$

So $f(x) = f^{(4)}(x) = f^{(8)}(x) = ... = f^{(948)}(x) = ... f^{(4n)}(x)$, with $n$ a positive integer.

Extending this, $f^{(k)}(x) = f^{(4n+k)}(x),$ with $n$ a positive integer and $0 \leq k < 4.$

Then,

$$f^{(950)}(x) = f^{(2)}(x) = f''(x) = - \sin x.$$

Comment: Thanks, I understand much better now. Just two questions though: what does $n$ represent and what does $k$ represent? I am just new to this notation.

Comment: The values of $n$ and $k$ are defined in the answer.  Another way of looking at it: the 1st, 5th, 9th, 13th ... derivatives are equal.  Also, the 2nd, 6th, 10th, 14th ... derivatives are equal.  The 3rd, 7th, 11th, 15th ... derivates are equal.  Finally, the function itself equals its 4th, 8th, 12th, 16th ... derivatives.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

Prove  that
$$\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\sin x=\sin\left(x+k\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

Comment: +1 helpful, thanks, what does k represent? I am just new to this notation.

Comment: @user436158 $k$ is any non negative integer and in your example just take $k=950$. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $\frac {d^{950}}{dx^{950}} \sin x$ usually means , take the $950$th derivative of $\sin x$ , i.e., differentiate the function $\sin x \;950$ times. But notice that the derivatives are periodic, i.e., they repeat after a certain number of times. $d/dx(\sin x)=\cos x; d/dx(\cos x)=-\sin x \dots$

Then $950$ goes on cycles of $4$ a certain number of times, with some left. How many?

Comment: They repeat after the 4th derivative...but how do I determine the answer?

Comment: @user436158:Check out the number of repetitions until you get to 950: 1st derivative equals the 5th= the 9th derivative=13th...; 2nd derivative equals the 6th=10th=...etc. Do you see it?

Comment: so since 2nd derivative = 6th = 10th...= (even)...= 950, the answer is $-\sin x$?

Comment: @user 436158: Yes, exactly.